# Can't boot from 22.04 on USB after installing 23.04

Tags: 22.04, live-usb, 23.04

After doing a clean install of Ubuntu 23.04, I realized that some applications I need are not supported by 23.04, so I decided to go back to 22.04.

I created a bootable USB disk using the 22.04 image and balenaEtcher, installed the USB disk in my laptop, then booted from the USB disk. Initially, this seems to work. I see the ASUS splash screen come up, then I see text showing up on the screen as part of the boot process. But then it goes back to the ASUS splash screen with "Ubuntu" below (this is what I usually see when the system starts normally) and boots from 23.04 instead.

It seems like the 22.04 USB installation starts, then sees the 23.04 installation and decides to boot from that instead, so that I am not able to run the 22.04 installer.

What's going on here? How can I run the Ubuntu 22.04 installer on the USB disk?

Comment: What kind of disk? Did you check that that download was successful, that the checksum of the iso file and on the disk matches that of the file `SHA256SUMS` at [this link](https://releases.ubuntu.com/jammy/)? See also [this link to the Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1958073&page=62&p=14142910#post14142910). -- Are you sure that the computer really boots from the USB drive (and not from the internal drive)? Check according to [this Ubuntu help link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick/bootUSB) and links from it.

Answer (score 0):

This turns out to have been a mistake on my part. Both my SSD and my USB disk showed up as SanDisk, and I simply chose the wrong one.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution :-)